# Oscillation of AdaBoost Training error

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, naive-bayes, adaboost

Adaboost, using weak learners as Gaussian Naive bayes, has oscillating/unpredictable training error as we increase the number of weak learners. Is there a specific reason for this? Y-axis is the training error and X-axis is the number of estimators.
[image]

Comment: Is that the training error of Adaboost or of each individuals learner?

Comment: Training error of Adaboost!